# Biztalk EDIFACT processing

Tags: biztalk, esb, edi, edifact

I'm trying to process an edifact file using Biztalk. I have setup a very simple map which is applied to send port. However, Biztalk complains about the message. I tried searching the net, but without any result. You can see the edi file [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3055964/MSCU10_AYSE%20NAZ%20BAYRAKTAR_1238A_POTI.EDI). I have setup parties and agreement using EDIFACT protocol, though I'm not sure how correctly I did. Whenever I try to provide biztalk with that message, I can see in event log the following message:

> A message received by adapter "FILE" on receive location "Receive
>   Location1" with URI "C:\Temp*.edi" is suspended.   Error details: An
>   output message of the component "Unknown " in receive pipeline
>   "Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.DefaultPipelines.EdiReceive,
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is suspended due to the following
>   error: 
>        Error: 1 (Field level error)     SegmentID: UNB  Position in TS: 1   Data Element ID: UNB5   Position in Segment: 5  Data Value:     37:
>   Invalid character(s) found in data element.  The sequence number of
>   the suspended message is 1.    MessageId: 
>   {DDE54B67-8907-49A2-BDE9-4763495B9B87}  InstanceID:
>   {892EC28B-AC4C-4EA4-8DCC-C49D5FC2869C}

I'm not sure what it means. Any help, indication would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you provide looks like a properly formatted EDIFACT message for syntax version 1 (Syntax version 4 is current). I don't know Biztalk, but you probably have to set something to make sure it is expecting syntax version 1. The UNA segment is different for syntax version 1 (it expects 5 delimiters) compared to the more recent syntax versions (where it expects 6 delimiters), so if Biztalk is expecting a UNA segment for a higher syntax version, then it won't be able to properly deal with the message.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your UNA5 (Repetition seperator) in your UNA specification line.

Without this, the BizTalk EDI disassembling pipeline is unable to correctly parse the content of your EDI file.

You will most likely need to coordinate with your trading partner(s) to ensure the UNA line (first line of the file) looks something like the following:

```
UNA:+,?*'
```

Comment: I tried that, but then I've got 149 errors instead of one :). Some of them was invalid character, some of them was invalid value. I correctly specified decimal delimiter and other properties in biztalk party configuration I think. I'm stuck. Maybe the document is not properly formatted at all?

Comment: The EDI is valid as syntax version 1. The UNA you refer to is used for higher syntax versions. Biztalk should be configured to handle syntax version 1 for this case.